# Java JSSC rs232 no events

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I'm trying to get some values from rs232 (card reader Roger prt66lt) with a java simple serial connetor (jssc) but it look like i dont get any events started. I'm using the example code. The card reader is set to send card number when he reads it. But i dont get any event started coz i dont see event that System.out. I'm including jssc.jar (from 2.5.0 version) and its connecting to divice. Is this version of jssc doesnt need any .dll ? I think its included in it ? The similar code to this one but with RXTX library works fine but i need to include attahed dll library.

Card reader send me HEX value: 02, 10 chars DATA, 0D, 0A, 03

Code:

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortEvent;
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class Main {

static SerialPort serialPort;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4"); 
    try {
        serialPort.openPort();//Open port
        serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params
        int mask = SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR + SerialPort.MASK_CTS + SerialPort.MASK_DSR;//Prepare mask
        serialPort.setEventsMask(mask);//Set mask
        serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader());//Add SerialPortEventListener
    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

static class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
 System.out.println("Event started");
        if(event.isRXCHAR()){//If data is available
            if(event.getEventValue() == 10){//Check bytes count in the input buffer
                //Read data, if 10 bytes available 
                try {
                    byte buffer[] = serialPort.readBytes(10);
                }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(event.isCTS()){//If CTS line has changed state
            if(event.getEventValue() == 1){//If line is ON
                System.out.println("CTS - ON");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("CTS - OFF");
            }
        }
        else if(event.isDSR()){///If DSR line has changed state
            if(event.getEventValue() == 1){//If line is ON
                System.out.println("DSR - ON");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("DSR - OFF");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Gravian, I am trying to determine if all serial libraries require a DLL. You are able to run without win32com.dll? I am assuming that is the DLL you referred to. Did you consider the old jar that you can download from MIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the default setting of RTS and DTR line is High so i need to use another setParams method and set the RTS line to false as needed by device.

Solution:

```
serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0, false, true);
```